# What will happen to the Files on update an Android App?

Tags: java, android

I have Android app ,which has 1.2 version.
In google playe import new version app:1.3
After Update I lose all files in me previous app.
All ok in Android 4.1.2 ,but in Android 4.2.2 i have this problem
This is my code:

```
   String HistoryFileName="History";
    if (!fileExistance(HistoryFileName)) {

    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(HistoryFileName,Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    HistoryModel jsObj=new HistoryModel(newBalance);
    balance=newBalance;
    String jsonString=gson.toJson(jsObj);  
    String jsonEncryptData = StringCrypto.encrypt(KEY,jsonString);

       fos.write(jsonEncryptData.getBytes());
       fos.flush();
       fos.close();
    }
    else{

        balance=GetHistoryItemsObject(HistoryFileName).balance; 

    }

public static boolean fileExistance(String fname)
{
    File file = context.getFileStreamPath(fname);
    if (file.exists()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**fileExistance(HistoryFileName)** get true, if i have that files, o.w false;
In 1.2 version i already  created  "History" File, but when i update my app,lose my File in Android 4.2.2, But in android 4.1.2 all ok.

Comment: Please post the `fileExistance` method body too.

Comment: And identify where you are storing files.

Comment: stored my files in data/data/com.playeroid./History